# Finding the maxima of a 3 variable function - basics

Tags: partial-derivative, maxima-minima

I am stuck on this problem and unfortunately the reading for my class does not include any example for finding a maxima of a 3 variable function.

$T(x,y,z) = -(x^2+y^2+z^2)+4x+8y+2z+11$ representing a temperature of a room.

I need to find the point $(x,y,z)$ where the temperature is at the maximum, and what is the value of this maximum.

Usually, for a two variable function, I would find the critical points of the function and see if the conditions for a maximum apply.

But for the function above, I do not know how to even start the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: As Siong Thye Goh has answered, you use the same procedure. In this particular case, you can find the maximum without calculus: the quadratic part is symmetric w/r all of the variables and one can find a translation that eliminates the linear terms, which will put the maximum at the new origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find partial derivatives and solve for partial derivatives equal zero. $$T(x,y,z) = -(x^2+y^2+z^2)+4x+8y+2z+11$$

$$T_x = -2x+4=0 \implies x=2$$
$$T_y = -2y+8=0 \implies y=4$$
$$T_z = -2z+2=0 \implies z=1$$

Since $$T_{xx}T_{yy}-T_{xy}T_{xy}=4>0$$

And $T_{xx}=-2<0$, the point $(2,4,1)$ is a maximizer.

the maximum value is  $T(2,4,1) =32$

Comment: My understanding of derivative is still shaky, what would $T_{xx},T_{yy}, T_{xy}$ mean in that case?

edit : just figured out that $T_{xx}$ means derivative of 2nd order.

Follow up question, why is $T_{z}$ not considered to find the maximizer?

Comment: This suffices to show it is concave downward, so the point is a maximum. I have posted another solution which is very straight forward.

Comment: hi, @MohammadRiazi-Kermani : I'm a bit rusty, so plaese forgive if my question is too simple. I'm susprised that the max/min for a function of 3 variables (x,y,z) only makes use of x,y, but not z. I thought the Jacobian or Hessian matrices, which include all variables ( when dealing with $$f(x_1,x_2,..., x_n)$$ were used. Why do we ignore the contribution of  $$f_z $$ here? Sorry, not strictly a Mathematical question, but a sort of "meta" question, about how information about one of the components --$$z$$-- here, is not used to find the max of $$f(x,y,z) $$

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Same procedure.

Find $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}$, equate them to zero and solve for the stationary point.

The hessian for this problem is $-2I$ which is negative definite, the stationary point is a minimal point.

Comment: You are going too fast for me. After solving the partial derivative, I would get $x=2,y=4,z=1$, meaning that I only have one critical point for that function (since the higher power is only $p^2$)

As for the hessian, I did not see that notion yet (I don't know if it will be covered later in my readings)

Comment: The graph is a “downward”-pointing paraboloid, so I don’t think that the lone stationary point is going to be a local minimum. Doesn’t a negative-definite Hessian indicate a *maximum*?

Comment: hmm... hessian is like the second derivative in higher dimension. Since you might not have learned it, for now, you might want to solve the problem as sum of three concave parabola.

Answer (score 2):

Let us  complete the squares.

$$T(x,y,z) = -(x^2+y^2+z^2)+4x+8y+2z+11 = $$

$$32-(x-2)^2 - (y-4)^2-(z-1)^2 \le 32$$

As you see the maximum value of $32$ is attained at $(2,4,1)$